# ExtJS Prevent validation for form fields with display: none

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I want to prevent validation for form fields with `display: none`.

For example fields with `ipv6` set to `display: none`, I dont want to check this fields with form `isValid()` method.

```js
var form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
  frame: true,
  bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 0;',
  items: [{
    xtype: 'radiogroup',
    id: 'ip_type',
    fieldLabel: 'IPType',
    columns: 2,
    items: [{
      boxLabel: 'IPv4',
      name: 'ip_type',
      inputValue: 'ipv4',
      checked: true
    }, {
      boxLabel: 'IPv6',
      name: 'ip_type',
      inputValue: 'ipv6'
    }],
    listeners: {
      'change': function(radioGroup, checkedRadio) {
        if (checkedRadio.inputValue == 'ipv4') {
          Ext.fly('ip').setStyle({
            display: 'block'
          });
          Ext.fly('ipv6').setStyle({
            display: 'none'
          });
          Ext.getCmp('ip').enable();
          Ext.getCmp('ipv6').disable();
        } else {
          Ext.fly('ip').setStyle({
            display: 'none'
          });
          Ext.fly('ipv6').setStyle({
            display: 'block'
          })
          Ext.getCmp('ip').disable();
          Ext.getCmp('ipv6').enable();
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    id: 'ip',
    layout: 'column',
    border: false,
    hideBorders: true,
    items: [{
      layout: 'form',
      items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'IP',
        xtype: 'ipv4field',
        name: 'ip',
        allowBlank: false,
        regex: ipv4_reg,
      }]
    }, {
      html: '/'
    }, {
      xtype: 'numberfield',
      name: 'netmask',
      allowBlank: false,
      allowDecimals: false,
      minValue: 0,
      maxValue: 32,
      width: 70
    }]
  }, {
    id: 'ipv6',
    layout: 'column',
    border: false,
    hideBorders: true,
    items: [{
      layout: 'form',
      items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'IP',
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'ipv6',
        allowBlank: false,
        regex: ipv6_reg,
      }]
    }, {
      html: '/'
    }, {
      xtype: 'numberfield',
      name: 'netmaskipv6',
      //allowBlank: false,
      allowDecimals: false,
      minValue: 0,
      maxValue: 128,
      width: 70
    }]
  }]

});
```

> 

Comment: can you add some code?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid validation of radio you can use [`Ext.form.Radio.disabled`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Radio-cfg-disabled) or if you want to send field value during form submit you can set [`Ext.form.Radio.validationEvent`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Radio-cfg-validationEvent) to `false`.

*Also its better to use ExtJS [`Ext.form.Radio.hidden`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Radio-cfg-hidden) property instead of css `display`.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the key problem is that I have a lot of hidden form elements, I don't want to they are detected, could not be set to disabled, and I hope that my display: block element to be detected